# How to fix TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'tuple' (CNN + Regr model)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I have created a model where I have multiple inputs - from table data and from .mat files.
The shape of the data extracted from the mat files is **(4701, 1, 52, 53)** the first number being the count of the records.
The shape of the table data is **(4701, 1404)**

This is my NN architecture:

```
inputs1 = Input(shape = (1, 52, 53))
model1 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=5, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(inputs1)
model1 = BatchNormalization()(model1)
model1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_first')(model1)

model1 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=3, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(model1)
model1 = BatchNormalization()(model1)
model1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_first')(model1)

model1 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=3, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(model1)
model1 = BatchNormalization()(model1)
model1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_first')(model1)

model1 = Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=3, padding = 'same', activation='relu')(model1)
model1 = BatchNormalization()(model1)
model1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_first')(model1)

flatten = Flatten()(model1)

inputs2 = Input(shape = (4701,))
model2 = Dense(4701, activation='relu')(inputs2)
model2 = Dropout(0.25)(model2)
model2 = Dense(538, activation = 'relu')(model2)
model2 = Dropout(0.25)(model2)
model2 = Dense(538, activation = 'relu')(model2)
model2 = Dropout(0.25)(model2)
model2 = Dense(264, activation = 'relu')(model2)

concat = Concatenate()([flatten, model2])

outputs = Dense(num_regr_outputs)(concat)
```

When I try to fit the data

```
combined_model.fit(
            x = [trainImagesX, trainDataX],
            y = trainDataY,
            validation_split = ([valImagesX, valDataX], valDataY),
            epochs = EPOCHS,
            batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
```

I get this error: ***TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'tuple'***.
I would appreciate if someone can tell me where is my mistake.

Comment: Please provide the dataset you are using? Without that, it's hard to confirm for answer

Comment: Here is a link to the data: https://www.kaggle.com/c/trends-assessment-prediction/data